# Why is the object produced when using std::bind with a lambda so large?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, lambda

The size of the object created by the bind is quite large compared to the lambda. It makes me question its efficiency. Does anyone have any input?

I'm using Linux on gcc 4.8.2

```
    auto f1 = [](int item, int N) { return item < N; };
    auto f2 = bind(f1, _1, 15);

    cout << "\nSize of lambda and bound lambda? "
         << sizeof(f1) << " " << sizeof(f2) << endl;
```

This outputs:

```
Size of lambda and bound lambda? 1 8
```

Comment: `sizeof(f1)` plus padding for alignment plus `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: There's moving applicable for instance, and what do you mean size compared to lambda? Also the lambda in question returns a `bool` (which isn't _large_ at all)?

Comment: @ildjarn Why doesn't libstdc++ nor libc++'s implementation make use of either EBO or the statelessness of the lambda?

Comment: @dyp : That's an implementation question that I'm not qualified to answer – perhaps Mr. Wakely or Mr. Hinnant can respond. ;-] I imagine that in general, `bind` cannot assume that the functor it's passed is both default-constructable and stateless, so a copy of it must be stored; but again, I'm not sure.

Comment: Makes sense that the bound parameter would get stuck to the resulting object. I guess it was wishful thinking that the compiler could optimize the parameter out because it is a constant.

Comment: @NathanDoromal That's why lambdas are much nicer than bind. In this case, you could easily write: `f2 = [f1](int item) { return f1(item,15); }`. It's a bit more verbose, but it is more efficient, smaller, and somewhat clearer (bind calls are often a bit quirky and unclear). Part of the issue with bind is that since lambdas exist, library implementers probably don't really care for optimizing bind calls anymore. I've even heard talks of deprecating bind in a future standard, since lambdas are far superior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The lambda in question is a stateless object.  Stateless objects in C++ must have a size of at least 1.

The `bind` simply stores a copy of the stateless object, followed by the value `15`.  The sizeof 15 (an `int`) is 4 bytes (on your system), but for efficiencies sake it aligns everything.  So the 1 byte lambda ends up taking up 4 bytes.

4+4=8

In theory, `std::bind` could try the empty base optimization to save storage for the function object if it was indeed empty (as is the case here).  However, as `bind` expressions are not intended for mass storage (like in an array) as the types they produce are opaque, that might be over-engineering: `bind`s result is intended to be stored locally (and barring extreme recursion an extra few bytes on the stack won't matter), or shoved into something like a `std::function` (where the free store memory tracking overhead makes an extra few bytes relatively unimportant).

But yes, a higher quality implementation could pull off a `4` byte `bind` result here.  You could probably brew your own using `std::tuple` with only a small mountain of headache, as `bind` is relatively quirky.

[`std::tuple` uses the empty base optimization](http://ideone.com/mljwF5) to store empty objects efficiently.  As you can see in that link, the size of a tuple containing an empty lambda and an `int` is `4`, the same size as the `int`.

...

The OP has asked why the `int` wasn't optimized away.  `std::bind` on most (all?) `std` libraries is implemented in-language.  That means it cannot take function parameters and use them to change the type of the function result.  It can only change the state of the run-time result.

The type of `std::bind( whatever, _1, 15 )` can only depend on the types of its arguments (and their value categories).  So whatever type that is could also be used to store `std::bind( whatever, _1, 7 )`.  The run time state, plus type, determine the logical behavior of the object returned.

While the name of the type returned is going to be implementation defined, as a library it exists, and in theory a function could return the first or second expression above based off an `if` statement.  (In C++11 or later return type deduction can be used to name the type as well).

So `sizeof` needs to fit that `int`.  Then the above describes why it is bigger than an `int`.

There are two mitigating factors here.  First, the object that `bind` returns need not actually exist in optimized code: the compiler can track the `15` and the object and do an as-if transformation to get rid of it.  This is sometimes hard to do, especially if you mess around with stuff like `std::function`, but it is possible.

Second, `std::bind` is a C++03 style way to create function objects.  It is quirky, and probably something you should avoid.  Lambdas have a slightly more verbose syntax but solve the problem better than `std::bind` does.

```
auto f2 = [f1](int y){ return f1(15,y); };
```

is an alternative to your `bind` that takes 1 byte of space instead of 8.  It behaves slightly differently than `bind` in a few ways.  First, it has a fixed type parameter `int` instead of `bind`'s unfixed one.  Second, it has a different type (a unique type for that lambda), and it doesn't have the strange interaction with other `std::bind` calls that return values from `std::bind` have.  There are probably other minor differences.

In C++14,

```
auto f2 = [f1](auto&& y){ return f1(15,std::forward<decltype(y)>(y)); };
```

would more closely mimic `std::bind`'s behavior with an untyped parameter instead of a typed one.

---

An alternative explanation to all of the above is that `int` is 8 bytes on your system and the `bind` uses the empty base optimization.  It is less likely.

Comment: I would have hoped that the compiler could optimize away the constant. I think it's a weakness when trying to apply the functional programming paradigm to C++. My currying is less efficient. I suppose I could try to use templated functors but it's not as nice as bind.

Comment: @NathanDoromal : In C++14 you can use generic lambdas instead of templated functors, and those are definitely nicer than bind (for most peoples' tastes).

Comment: @Nath try `auto f2 = [f1](int y){ return f1(15,y); };`.  `std::bind` was written prior to lambdas existing in C++11.  Or `auto f2 = [f1](auto&& y){ return f1(15,y); };` if you don't want to bind the type in C++14.  Here `sizeof(f2)==1`.  The compiler may optimize away the entire `bind` object in release, but if you ask how big the structure is it will tell you its unoptimized size -- it treats it as a type.  It has the same type as another bind with `7` passed instead of `15`.